# What is the simplest, currently functional way to save sessions in Connect?

Tags: session, node.js, connect, express

I cannot find a list of session store implementations that work with Connect in node.js. Connect-Redis works great, but requires Redis and I'd rather avoid that dependency. Sesame/nStore would be ideal but no longer appears to work at all. Sesame/supermarket requires fiddling with node-waf in order to work, and I'd like to avoid that as well.

Comment: WHy not implement your own session store. Connect gives you sessions.

Comment: Why do it if there's a better/simpler option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty currently functional way to save sessions I'd recommend using [dirty](https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty).

It's just a key value store, but it doesn't take much to hook up to connect sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Connect comes with a default in-memory session store. Dirty lets you to implement a in-memory session store backed up to disk. It won't allow you to save memory space, it merely adds persistence to your store, and I doubt a persistent session store has much use.

Why do you need a persistent session store? What requirements to a session store are not implemented by the default session store provided by connect? Is it only persistence, or you have something else in mind?

Comment: I needed the persistance for a few reasons, the main one being that I had no control over when the box would reboot or when my service would be interrupted, and the sessions were up to several weeks long.